# Umbraco Change Type of Multiple Media Picker To List<Image>

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I add to my umbraco DataType a Multiple Data Pickers (One Of an Archetype )

I Want in my model change the type from the string with comma to `List<Image>`

I found this code :

```
var list= item.HasValue("media") ?
 item.GetValue<List<PublishedContentExtended>>("media").OfType<Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Image>().ToList() 
: new List<Image>();
```

But when i try add this code to my Project I got an error

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent.PublishedContentExtended>' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and the best extension method overload 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.OfType<T>(Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent)' has some invalid arguments
```

[image]

And this is my Image Class

[image]

How can I change the String separated by comma to List Of Image Type

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OfType does a type check and filters the list.  If  `item.GetValue("images")` does indeed give you an enumerable of IPublishedContent you would want to call: `Select(_ => new Image(_))` instead.

If however item.GetValue("images") just gives you the comma delimited string you'd need to split and select. Something like:

```
item.GetValue("images").Split(',').Select(_ => Umbraco.Media(_)).Select(_ => new Image(_))
```